# Building cocos2dx project in android

Tags: android, android-ndk, cocos2d-x-2.x

x 2.6 programming and I was trying my hands on with hello world project and while running the ./build_native I am getting the following error and there is not much help on this error on the Internet.

```
Android NDK: NDK Application 'local' targets unknown ABI(s): armeabi    
Android NDK: Please fix the APP_ABI definition in ./jni/Application.mk    
/Users/jitenagarwal/Documents/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702/android-ndk-r10b/build/core/setup-app.mk:112: *** Android NDK: Aborting    .  Stop.
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to this tutorial:
http://2sa-studio.blogspot.fr/2013/04/setup-cross-platform-project-with.html

Cocos2dx 2.6 works only with NDK r9d.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have installed only the 64 bit half of NDK r10b. Either unpack the 32 bit half of it (in the same location, so that the same android-ndk-r10b directory gets completed), or update to r10c or r10d, which contain all of it in one single package.

Comment: yea i tried that and it helped me remove that error but another error raised which is preventing creation of .so file and following is the error          make: *** No rule to make target `/Users/mohitrangaraju/cocos2d-x-2.2.6/projects/game/proj.android/../../../extensions/AssetsManager/AssetsManager.cpp', needed by `obj/local/armeabi/objs/cocos_extension_static/AssetsManager/AssetsManager.o'.  Stop.
make: Leaving directory `/Users/jitenagarwal/cocos2d-x-2.2.6/projects/game/proj.android'